# Displaying images from file inputs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, file, input

I need to run a function when someone has finished selecting a file using the file input service. By "file input service", I mean:

```
<input type="file" name = "foo" id="foo">
```

I have tried to do this in various ways, first by creating a form to do so and using other techniques, but nothing seems to work. There are several ways to detect if the thing has something, like by using:

```
document.getElementById("foo").files[0]
```

This only returns a value if you run it, but I cannot constantly compile a while statement to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pure Javascript

You can use pure javascript like below. This code basically uses [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to get the input element, and [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) to do something when the input field is changed.

```js
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("change", function() {
  console.log("Changed");
});
```

```html
<input type="file" name="foo" id="foo">
```

### jQuery

Use jQuery [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/). Basically, this code will `console.log` "Changed" when the input changes (you add a file).

```js
$("#foo").change(function() {
  console.log("Changed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="foo" id="foo">
```